# How to customize dialog fragment title with image view and button?

Tags: android, dialog, android-dialogfragment

I have a dialog fragment where i need to show call log details of a person on call log list item click. I need to show display photo and a button instead of title of dialog fragment. I also tried to remove title and put photo and button but width is wrapping the content and dialog size shrinks. I need width to fill parent, or match as the parent activity.

Comment: Could you show us what you have tried so far?

Comment: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html#CustomLayout

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My problem is fixed. Before i was trying to fix layout in xml,now i added layout width and height in the onStart method of my dialog fragment and removed title using FEATURE_NO_TITLE flag. Here is the code :

```
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        Dialog dialog = super.onCreateDialog(savedInstanceState);

        // request a window without the title
        dialog.getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);

        return dialog;
    }
    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();

// safety check
        if (getDialog() == null) {
            return;
        }

        int dialogWidth =  --- // specify a value here
        int dialogHeight = --- // specify a value here
        getDialog().getWindow().setLayout(dialogWidth, dialogHeight);
}
```